# Prevent image from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I am looking for a way to prevent image from being loaded.

I have created 2 buttons, one is for `previous` image and the other button is for the `next` image. When the user clicks, the `next` button, I just simply change the `src` of the image and display the next url. The problem about this is when the user clicks the `next` button fast enough. The `src` will be changed multiple times and it will still load all those src or image link that is being passed down. This will cause to slow down the server.

My goal is to prevent all these images from being loaded, and just display the current `src` where the user stops.

Comment: use javascript promises, disable the next/prev button until the image loads and then enable back again

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.stop()` or `.clearQueue()` method on the click event of the "Next/Prev" links, this will stop the loading of all the images at once.

Ex:
**HTML Code**

```
<div id="hoverme-stop-2">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
$( "#hoverme-stop-2" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).find( "div" ).stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
}, function() {
  $( this ).find( "div" ).stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
});
```

You can compare the behavior by removing/adding the stop() from the code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: that is just an example, you can add your `click` event after stop() which will stop the continuous click on any element.